# How to correctly pass NSFetchedResultsController's numberOfObjects from one VC to another?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a VC1 with a UITableView which populate it cells with a NSFetchedResultsController. I want VC1 tableView to place all new added cells to the bottom of tableView, therefore I created a CoreData attribute: `itemNumberForVC1`(type Int32). The cells can be added only from VC2. That's why I need to pass the `numberOfObjects` from VC1 method `numberOfRowsInSection` to VC2.

The `numberOfObjects` is in the following method of VC1:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   guard let numberOfObjects = fetchedResultsController.sections?[section].numberOfObjects else {return 0}
   return numberOfObjects
}
```

I need to use the `numberOfObjects` in my VC2 `didSelectRowAt` method:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let currency = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    currency.isForConverter = !currency.isForConverter

    //currency.itemNumberForVC1 = numberOfObjects - 1 <- calculation: there I should receive the actual 
    //number of objects from VC1 and assign the number to picked currency, and it should appear in VC1 
    //at the bottom of its TableView

    coreDataManager.save()
}
```

I tried to use delegates but inside VC2 `didSelectRowAt` the result is always 0. The max result I've got is created a method in VC2, which takes `numberOfObjects` as a parameter, call it in VC1 and then I have that number inside the VC2 but only in borders of the method. I can't move it to VC2 `didSelectRowAt` (tried through a global variable).

How can I do that efficiently?

Comment: How are you passing `numberOfObjects` to VC2. Also what is 0 ? Is `numberOfObjects` 0 in VC2, is the calculation `numberOfObjects - 1` 0 or something else ? Also, from what I understand the end goal is to just know what are the new items added to CoreData when you return back to VC1 from VC2 ?

Comment: @ShawnFrank, thank you for the answer. The thing is I don't know how to pass numberOfObjects to VC2 so it can be available in borders of VC2 didSelectRowAt method. 0 - is a result of numberOfObjects which I received when tried to use delegate method to send it from VC1 to VC2 and then through global variable use in VC2 didSelectRowAt. The end Goal is to track how much objects I have in VC1 tableView and according to that number in VC2 assign amount to a picked currency.itemNumberForVC1. Because VC1 tableView will sort items based on itemNumberForVC1 attribute (sortDescriptor)

Comment: How do you go from VC1 to VC2 - is it some kind of segue ? I am thinking you just need to add some kind of object to VC2 like `var numberOfObjectsInVC1 = 0`. Then when you are about to transition to VC2 from VC1, you have to do something like `let vc2 = VC2(); vc2.numberOfObjectsInVC1 = numberOfObjectsInFetchContr`. If you are using segues then above code will be in something like `prepare for segue`

Comment: @ShawnFrank no, I don't use segues. VC2 shows all possible currencies user can pick to display in VC1. When user picks currency, its bool attribute "pickedforVC1" changes on true and then VC1 shows it based on predicate. But for now it sorts everything based on currency attribute shortName (EUR, USD), I want it to be sorted by position (so every picked currency shows in last position on VC1 tableView). That's why I need attribute itemNumberForVC1. And to set it I need to know how much cells now in VC1 tableView. What to do if there is no segues?

Comment: I think issue is getting property to VC2 correct ? For me it is a bit of a challenge to understand the flow a bit. Maybe if you can add some info like `1. Code of how you transition from VC1 to VC2` and `2. Maybe some screenshot or GIF of interaction to go from VC1 to VC2 back to VC1 and some explanation of what working output should look like` - this will help me understand a bit better and advice if I can

Comment: @ShawnFrank, sure, take a look at the GIF: https://cln.sh/o6IRWJ. There I pick BRL in VC2 and FRC adds it to VC1 straight I picked it. Then picked AUD. The goal is to place AUD below BRL in VC1, not above. It's place above now because FRC sort it by shortName, I created attribute itemNumberForVC1 to implement sort by position. In VC2 didSelectRowAt I should set that attribute based on how much now cells in VC1: returns 2 - then I should assign itemNumberForVC1 to 3, then in VC1 when sortDescriptor will be by itemNumberForVC1 it'll place third cell to the bottom after 2 cells, not before them.

Comment: Ok I see. I would recommend to change the approach a bit if you can because I think passing data to VC2 as object and then syncing this data back to CoreData - something is not going smooth here. My recommendation is to create `addedOn` attribute to your entity which should be of type `Date` When saving new item, save the current Date and time in this attribute. When coming back to VC1, make fetched results controller sort by the `addedOn` date property in descending order so the latest is first.

Comment: @ShawnFrank, yes, that can be a solution, thank you! But can you advice: later I wanted to implement cells drag'n'drop in VC1: user drag cell at row 5 and drop to row 1 for example. If my sortDescriptor will be set up to Date(), then dragged cell will remain at last row... Before your solution I thought to use itemNumberForVC1 (Int) for both of that cases.

Comment: Actually in that case, then your original solution is good and the right one. Do not add the date added as it will only fix the situation temporarily and your original thinking and planning was good. Can you add the code of how you currently go from VC1 to VC2 and how you currently pass the `numberOfObjects` to VC2. We can continue this discussion in chat if you like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241925/discussion-between-shawn-frank-and-artexhibit).